# Assignment to element of array by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with two object elements. and here are two functions `fuction1(myArray)` and `function2()`.

`fuction1(myArray)` : in this function I assign first element of object to a new variable then assign a new object to this variable but it doesn't any effect to real array.

`fuction1(myArray)` : but in second function I alson assigned first element to a new varible then assign a new string to value of object and it has effect to real array.

I understand a little bit about how these processes happen, but I couldn't understand how it works exactly.

```js
function fuction1(myArray) {
    var firstElement = myArray[0];
    firstElement = {
        new: "newElement"
    };
}

function fuction2(myArray) {
    var firstElement = myArray[0];
    firstElement.new = "newElement";
}

var arr = [
    {y: "yElement"}, 
    {x: "xElement"}
];
    
fuction1(arr);
console.log(arr); // array element doesn't change

fuction2(arr);
console.log(arr); // array element value is changed
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `var firstElement = myArray[0];` You are first setting the variable `firstElement` with the value of `myArray[0]`.

And then, in `firstElement = { new:"newElement" };` you are setting to the same variable a **different object**.

The content of the array ins't changed because the second statement changes the values of the local variable `firstElement` only.

---

In the second case, you are first doing the same. `var firstElement = myArray[0];`.

Then, you are **manipulating the object** by adding a property with a value `firstElement.new ="newElement";`

Since you are using `firstElement.SomeThing`, you are still working on the same object you get and your array is changed.

---

```js
function fuction1(myArray) {
  var firstElement = myArray[0]; // firstElement contains the object in myArray[0]
  firstElement = { 
    new:"newElement" 
  }; // firstElement contains now another object and has nothing to do with myArray[0] anymore
}
        
function fuction2(myArray) {
  var firstElement = myArray[0];  // firstElement contains the object in myArray[0]
  firstElement.new ="newElement"; // firstElement is still a reference to the object and a property is added
}  

function fuction3(myArray) {
  myArray[0] = { 
    new:"newElement" 
  };
}

var arr = [
  {   
    y:'yElement'
  },
  {
    x:"xElement"
  }
];

  

fuction1(arr);
console.log(arr); // array element doesn't change

fuction2(arr);
console.log(arr); // array element value is changed

fuction3(arr);
console.log(arr); // array element value is changed
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. In the first case, a different object was assigned to the firstElement variable, it changed with the reference that holds a new object.

Comment: @sadullahzolfqar yes indeed